# Alternative to Softerra's LDAP Administrator?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am looking for an alternative to [Softerra's LDAP Administrator](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/), simply for the price is over-budget for a small team to test the LDAP credentials.

So I really appreciate if someone can point me to some other alternatives for a Windows-based environment. We've got our Active Directory setup already, I only need a tool to confirm the access as a proof to customers. Sorry I am not a security guru, I am quite the opposite...

Thanks for any suggestion in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Softerra LDAP Browser v.4.5](http://ldapbrowser.com/info_softerra-ldap-browser.htm) is a free alternative to Softerra LDAP Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to use free Eclipse-based [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/)?

Answer (score 1):

While Apache DS is nice and functional, it is quite heavy on disk and memory.

I personally prefer [LBE](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8652/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282) which is about 600K, Java and the same JAR works on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Also much faster to start and configure than Apache DS.  What I love about Apache DS is that you can export to CSV or XLS (Though that never works for me) instead of just LDIF.  When I need CSV output, I fire up ApacheDS just for that.